# URL formatting using htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to make custom urls for my site for example I want url like

```
http://www.mysite.com/first-link-page/
http://www.mysite.com/second-link-page/
```

Here, first-link-page,second-link-page,... etc is not folder for each link. It is dynamically generated pages using .htaccess file. I used comman templet file to which I pass varibles(i.e. value like first-link-page for example) and based on that page is display. In .htaccess file I use following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/$ mytemplet.php?parameter=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This works fine. But if in browser user typed

```
http://www.mysite.com/first-link-page    //without slash at ending
http://www.mysite.com/second-link-page
```

It gives page not found error. I want .htaccess to automatically add slash at end so that my url works fine. How do I do that. Please Help.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[To make a single character optional in a regex, just put a question mark efter it.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)

That would make your rewriterule;

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ mytemplet.php?parameter=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note the question mark after the / you want to be optionally matched against your URL.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your solution works fine thanks for that but is there any way by which I can add last slash automatically so that I get url with slash added at end.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your rewrite rule is that it will work only if it finds a slash at the end. To amend this, you should make the slash optional, like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ mytemplet.php?parameter=$1 [QSA,L]
```